# hub.docker.io reports tags in the web interface but we cannot some of them using the API

Tags: docker, dockerhub

We have a private docker registry at hub.docker.io and we discovered that the api does not return all the tags that are visible in the web interface.

API call like `https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/company/reponame/tags` returns a list that is not the same as the one we are seeing on https://hub.docker.com/r/company/reponame/tags/

Why do we get this and how can we overcome this?

These tags were added more than 17 hours ago, so I doubt is a caching issue. Also we are using the same credentials to access them.

Answer (score 0):

My impression is that this is product bug so I raised a ticket on https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/687